# can't collect docker metrics using prometheus

Tags: docker, monitoring, prometheus

I want to monitor the Docker engine. I am following "[Collect Docker metrics with Prometheus](https://docs.docker.com/config/thirdparty/prometheus)" to configure the [Docker daemon for metrics](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) which can be later collected and analyzed with Prometheus.

On my PC (OS version is CentOS 7.4, Docker version is 17.12.0.ce), I have pasted the following to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "metrics-addr" : "0.0.0.0:9323",
  "experimental" : true
}
```

Then, starting the Prometheus instance, I found the connection between Prometheus and Docker daemon is failed.

**Error log**

```
Get http://localhost:9323/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9323: connect: connection refused
```

What can I do next?

Comment: what is your `prometheus.yaml` file?

Comment: - job_name: 'docker'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9323']

Comment: did you tried `"metrics-addr" : "127.0.0.1:9323"` ?

Comment: yes, i tried, but failed. i try to use curl http://localhost:9323/metrics on local machine, it's OK. but prometheus instance still can't connect to docker.

Answer (score 5):

Get docker ip addres

```
ip addr show docker0
```

Enter docker ip addres in prometherus.yml configuration

```
    static_configs:
  - targets: ['172.17.0.1:9323']
```

[image]

Comment: It works. thanks. Can you explain why `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` don't work

Comment: @haj_baba: probably because prometheus is inside container, but 9323 port is on host machine.

Answer (score 4):

In respect to your question

> What can I do next?

after changing the configuration in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` it will be necessary to

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

You may check after this if the port 9323 is in state `LISTEN`

```
lsof -Pi TCP -a -c dockerd
```

As you mentioned in your comment that

```
curl http://$(hostname):9323/metrics
```

is working properly on your local host, it indicates a problem with(in) your network.

As the Prometheus service is usually running somewhere else you may check if there is a connection from the remote machine to your Docker host. For this you could use something like

```
root@prometheusHost:/# nc -vz dockerHost 9323
```

It will give you a hint if the connection is refused, e.g. by a firewall.

Comment: Reloading the daemon is what made it worked for me without anything further.

Comment: What if docker is on host machine, but prometheus inside container?

Answer (score 3):

### Configure the Docker daemon

> NOTE: `0.0.0.0` *i.e. all IP addresses on the local machine*

#### `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "metrics-addr" : "0.0.0.0:9323",
  "experimental" : true
}
```

### Open firewall port `9323` `--permanently`

```sh
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=9323/tcp
success
```

#### A few checks

Check, remember to list `--permanent` configuration, or it won't show

```sh
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --list-all
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 9323/tcp                            <= OPEN
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

```sh
$ sudo lsof -Pi TCP -a -c dockerd
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
dockerd-c 28157 root   14u  IPv6 30732963      0t0  TCP *:9323 (LISTEN)
...
```

Check connection to `localhost`

```
nc -vz localhost 9323
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to ::1:9323.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.03 seconds.
```

Check connection to host IP *e.g. 10.223.37.14*

```
$ nc -vz 10.223.37.14 9323
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 10.223.37.14:9323.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.03 seconds.
```

#### Check the metrics acccess using `curl`

```sh
curl http://localhost:9323/metrics
```

or using the IP from another machine

```sh
curl http://10.223.37.14:9323/metrics
```

You will get a connection refused if the port is not open

```sh
curl http://10.223.37.14:9323/metrics
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.223.37.14 port 9323: Connection refused
```

but once it's open, you will be able to see the metrics

```sh
$ curl http://10.223.37.14:9323/metrics
# HELP engine_daemon_container_actions_seconds The number of seconds it takes to process each container action
# TYPE engine_daemon_container_actions_seconds histogram
engine_daemon_container_actions_seconds_bucket{action="changes",le="0.005"} 1
engine_daemon_container_actions_seconds_bucket{action="changes",le="0.01"} 1
engine_daemon_container_actions_seconds_bucket{action="changes",le="0.025"} 1
engine_daemon_container_actions_seconds_bucket{action="changes",le="0.05"} 1
engine_daemon_container_actions_seconds_bucket{action="changes",le="0.1"} 1
engine_daemon_container_actions_seconds_bucket{action="changes",le="0.25"} 1
engine_daemon_container_actions_seconds_bucket{action="changes",le="0.5"} 1
engine_daemon_container_actions_seconds_bucket{action="changes",le="1"} 1
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run Prometheus from a container, you can consider the below address:

```
host.docker.internal:9323
```

Add this to your prometheus.yml inside your Prometheus container.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue, here's the fix:
**$ sudo vi /etc/hosts**

```
0.0.0.0 <hostname> host
```

*0.0.0.0 can be substituted with the advertised address in Docker Swarm*